# Can file uploads time out in PHP?

Tags: php, upload

Hi im quite new to PHP, i have created a form for very large csv files to be uploaded to my server. Some one mentioned to me that the browser can time out due to the uploading file being to big, is this true? and if so, can it be prevented?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need a proper value for the following php.ini settings:

1. [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) (**not** max_execution_time!)
2. [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
3. [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

and maybe

4. [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Comment: The PHP documentation for max_input_time says: "It is measured from the moment of receiving all data on the server to the start of script execution." So why would the file size make a difference?  All the data have been received before this timer starts.

Comment: After testing I confirm that `max_input_time` seems to have no effect on this issue.

Comment: I have faced similar issue. 
When I used to upload file from desktop, it was working fine. But if the same page is used to upload same image from mobile, it used to fail. 
The error reported on server was due to max file size. Actually, the issue was due to more time taken for image uploading from mobile causing the timeout. 

After increasing `MAX_INPUT_TIME`, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 31):

There are some configuration directives that can cause large uploads to fail if their values are too small:

PHP

- **[`max_input_time`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)**   Maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST, GET and file uploads
- **[`upload_max_filesize`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)**   Maximum size of an uploaded file.
- **[`post_max_size`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)**   Maximum size of post data allowed.

Apache

- **[`TimeOut`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout)**   Amount of time the server will wait for certain events before failing a request
- **[`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)**   Restricts the total size of the HTTP request body sent from the client

There are probably some more than this.

Comment: i have no idea where abouts to even go to edit the apache settings :(

Comment: Ask your provider if these settings are proper to upload large files.

Answer (score 7):

A good way to work around the poor handling of large file uploads in php, is to use an uploader like [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/) which will split the file into chunks before sending them. This also has the benefit for your users that they get a proper progress feedback while uploading, and they can upload multiple files in one go.

Answer (score 6):

I was able solve this problem using the following settings, you could use different values but you get the idea:

For my server, I put these lines in a ".user.ini" file inside the script directory, your server may look for a different file, if you do a phpinfo('user_ini.filename') on the server it will spit out the file you need to put your values in

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = -1
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
memory_limit = 256M
```

Comment: Yes, perfect. But 1800 sec (30 min).

Answer (score 3):

When uploading very large files, you have to change 4 configuration variables:

- `upload_max_filesize`
- `post_max_size`
- `memory_limit`
- `time_limit`

Time limit may be increased at runtime with set_time_limit().

Comment: To my knowing there's no such directive in PHP - time_limit. set_time_limit() sets max_execution_time.

Answer (score 2):

A script is allowed to run, by default, for something like 30 seconds.  You can use the [set_time_limit() function](https://www.php.net/set_time_limit) to alter this.  Also, if your user will need to upload large files, you'll need to change the post_max_size and/or the upload_max_filesize values in your php.ini file.

Also, if you want to just extend your timeout limit globally, you can change max-execution-time in php.ini.

Comment: brilliant, thanks for that! i didnt even know about post_max_size or upload_max_file_size! very much apreciated

Comment: set_time_limit affects the same setting as max_execution_time in php.ini.  The doc says "The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc."  Does the file upload count as a "stream operation"?  If so, then it appears that this setting won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true. File upload is done through a POST request and requests in general are subject to timeout. You should be able to reconfigure your environment for a longer request timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just timeouts that can cause problems. There are some limits on the maximum size of file that can be uploaded. These limits can be changed in the php.ini file:

post_max_size
   upload_max_filesize
   memory_limit

Check out http://uk.php.net/ini.core for details.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not directly related to your original question, but if you have a reverse proxy load balancer in front of your PHP script, the load balancer can timeout or block large uploads.  Always check your load balancer's configuration if you support file uploads.  Just like PHP, most load balancers default settings for uploads are pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

If changing any of the above parameters doesn't seem to make any difference, it can be that a html form somewhere contains the name MAX_FILE_SIZE as a hidden field.

`<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">`

In the example above, any file over 10MB will not be uploaded.