# AFHTTPRequestOperation fail

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am developing an app which perform following task.

1. Fetch gallery images and display in grid view.
2. after selecting images, they will be uploaded to server

I use "POST" method for upload.
It is working fine into iPhone simulator.
But into iPhone 5 device, it will create following error after some progress of uploading.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1f0ba650 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.25/webservices/uploadphoto.php/?user_id=22, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.25/webservices/uploadphoto.php/?user_id=22, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1f0a3b60 "The request timed out."}
```

Here, my code for uploading.

```
    -(void)uploadImageWithStatus:(NSData *)data filenumber:(NSInteger)filenumber{ NSUserDefaults *defaultUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *userId = [defaultUser stringForKey:@"UserId"];

        AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",UploadURL,userId]]];
        client.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount =1;

        //You can add POST parameteres here

        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

            //This is the image
            [formData appendPartWithFileData: data name:@"f" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_image.jpeg",rand()] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

        }];


       NSLog(@"Time out : %f",[request timeoutInterval]);
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {


            //        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

}];
        //Setup Completeion block to return successful or failure
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSString *response = [operation responseString];
            NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
            if(error.code == -1001){
            UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                              message:@"The request timed out." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [myAlert show];
            }
            //Code to Run if Failed

        }];

        [operation start];
```

I will be very thankful, if anyone can help me. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're receiving is a time-out error: the server you're trying to contact is failing to respond in a timely fashion.

I notice that you're trying to connect to `192.168.1.25`, a local IP address. Is it possible that you are running a server locally on your development machine (so the iPhone simulator works fine), but can't access this on your iPhone device as it's on a different network?

The best way to test this is to go into Mobile Safari and load up `192.168.1.25`. If it doesn't work, you'll know the problem isn't with your code, but is with how your network is set up.

Comment: hi,thanks for answer. I open 192.168.1.25 in mobile safari. It opened without any problem. And as i told in question that some progress is done, and after some progress error occur.

Comment: Then it sounds as if your upload is getting interrupted at some point.  You might not see this on the simulator as it's somewhat faster than the actual device. Have you checked your PHP configuration? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php

Comment: I am iphone developer, i will send this link to php developer. so it will take some time.

Comment: we have set following values into php.....:  
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

Comment: And is that still not working? I'd suggest trying to proxy your connection to the iPhone, so you can see what's actually happening at a network level.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to proxy my connection to iPhone.