# Continuous file uploads?

Tags: php, file-upload

Some files has to be uploaded to system. Mostly around 5-10MB JPG files.
However, users usually have a very slow upload speed, so it exceeds max_execution_time() most of the time.

I don't have permission to modify max_execution_time()

Is there anything I can do on this case?

Comment: It's rather hackish, but what about having them upload the image to a third party image hosting site and input the URL into the form instead?

Comment: Are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php

Comment: Can we do this task in other ways? Like, using websockets to make a continious connection with user and receiving data, or reading first bytes in first 30 seconds (and if 30 seconds exceeds) do another call to the page where we've stopped. @BjørneMalmanger; Yes. @Mike; Like which? It shouldn't be a just image hosting website. I need some API's to keep track of images, or even; let user resize picture on my hosting, save cropped image on 3rd party website using an API. The website I'm making is basically a canvas painting website, so they can get their house walls painted etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set using `ini_set()`:

```
$max_execution_time = 1000; // or whatever value you need
ini_set('max_execution_time', $max_execution_time);
```

Comment: Actually it should be `max_input_time`

Comment: I can't set PHP ini settings, because it's a shared hosting.

Comment: @ChrisOlsson You should talk to your hosting provider to see what they can do.  Or better yet, just get off of shared hosting... it is the devil's business.