# Fine-uploader and PHP Server - Problems with big files (>900MB)

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I set up fine-uploader and created a PHP Server handler which is instancing the qqfileuploader.php. Everything works perfectly fine, until I try to upload large files. Up to 600-700 MB it works great, now I tried a file of 909 MB:

log:

```
FineUploader 3.8.2] Sending upload request for 3
```

It is uploading, but when the progressbar reaches 100%, it starts again at 0%. Then it shows "proccessing.." and again a progressbar. Then after a while:

Log:

```
[FineUploader 3.8.2] xhr - server response received for 3 
[FineUploader 3.8.2] responseText =  
[FineUploader 3.8.2] Received response status 0 with body:  
[FineUploader 3.8.2] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (Unexpected end of input)
```

On my local machine it's working even with the same file. The problem appears only when done on my webhosting. post_max size and upload file size is set properly. What else can I do?

This is my serverside upload handling method:

```
public function doUpload()
    {   
        $uploader = new qqFileUploader('uploads');
        $uploader->allowedExtensions = array();
        $uploader->sizeLimit = 1200 * 1024 * 1024; // 1.2GB

        $uploader->inputName = 'qqfile';

        $uploader->prefix = $_SESSION['identifier']; //file prefix

        $uploader->chunksFolder = 'chunks';

        $result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads');

        $result['uploadName'] = $uploader->getUploadName();

        header("Content-Type: text/plain");
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Comment: What browser?  Have you looked at all of your server logs?  What did you find?

Comment: Thanks, I think I found it: 
[Tue Sep 10 15:24:35 2013] [error] [client **.**.**.**] ModSecurity: Request body (Content-Length) is larger than the configured limit (805306368). [hostname "***"] [uri "/de/upload/doUpload"]

Unfortunately, I can't increase this value. So I probably have to use chunking..which unfortunately didn't work for me when I tried to use it yesterday.

Comment: If you are having issues with chunking, you'll need to open up a new question and provide specifics.  If you are seeing issues, it is likely due to your server code, as chunking works without issues in Fine Uploader in all capable browsers.  Note that chunking is not possible in IE9 and older.

Comment: ok chunking is working, except in (like you said) IE9. So I assume in IE9 and older, if chunking is enabled, it is just uploading the file in the classic way in one piece right? So I probably need chunking and to increase this ModSecurity value for older browsers.

Comment: Correct, in IE9 and older, the entire file will be sent in one request.

Answer (score 3):

You need a proper value for the following php.ini settings:

1. **max_input_time** (not max_execution_time!)
2. **upload_max_filesize**
3. **post_max_size**

And maybe

**memory_limit**

**Source:** [Can file uploads time out in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php) from @Ionuț G. Stan