# Debugging techniques for a PHP script with many, many file uploads?

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I have a PHP script which services a form that contains many, many file uploads.  There's about 40 separate files being uploaded, although each one is less than 30 KB in size (so about a meg, total of actual data is being transfered).

I'm using CakePHP for this, if it somehow makes a difference.

The problem I'm having is that only 19 of the files are being uploaded (once they're uploaded I send out an email using GMail as an SMTP relay).  I've checked the obvious things, such as listed here:

[Can file uploads time out in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php)

And I've got generous values for everything.

Could anyone suggest strategies to use for running down this problem and/or specific things to check?

Comment: First, follow the progress in your browser and note any error. In Chrome (and other webkit things) you have "Devtools" panel (hit <Ctrl+Shift+I> to show, Network pane); in Firefox, you have an extension, Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much, much digging it looks like it was a problem with my SMTP setup.  I couldn't tell you how or why, but the problem was that attempting to email a zillion emails (well, ~40) caused the PHP process to halt (no error messages, nothing).  Running the exact same code under XDebug worked fine, and putting a quarter-second sleep() after each email appears to work.

(On a semi-related note: Is there a way to delete a StackOverflow question that you've asked? :) )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a CakePHP issue. Apache and php have certain limits on number of files and max size of files that can be uploaded at a time. Also there will be max post size.

There are two ways to overcome this

1. You can override the settings in .htaccess file like

   ```
   php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
   php_value post_max_size 15M
   php_value max_file_uploads 50
   ```
2. Change it in php.ini file and restart server.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is a CakePHP issue either, but I figured that I'd mention it for completeness' sake.

Comment: I tried adjusting the above parameters but sadly it didn't help.

I kinda suspect that it's a problem with GMail, although I've got no idea how to run that down...

Comment: Is there any security patch like 'suhosin' installed in your server. 'suhosin' patch usually override php settings. You have to change suhosin settings in that case.