# Possible to prevent server from timing out when uploading bulk images?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, file-upload, multi-upload

We have a site on Wordpress and use Woocommerce for our commerce site.  In short we have a front end form that logged in users can upload multiple images at once.  Problem is these images are typically straight off a digital camera and we need to keep them at the highest resolution possible.

When users try uploading even 50+ images it takes FOREVER and sometimes doesn't even complete, it will return a 504 error.

We talked to the host and have done all we can with them to decrease server timeouts and they suggested making edits to the attached script.  I also went in to the wp_config file and set the max upload size to something like 256M.

This problem is still happening and I was just wondering if anyone had any recommendations on how to prevent server timeouts or speed up image uploads without totally reworking the code?

The attached code is here: http://pastebin.com/AHTDNaDL

Just to save some time while browsing that file lines 3 -175 handle the product creation for each image uploaded; line 253 - 340 is the upload form and line 447 starts the binding functions.

I have been at this for days and googled everything from plugins to ajax uploaders but still not having much luck, thinking some outside input would help

**Edit:**
Since it doesn't look like I will be able to configure my server to what I need, is it possible to break the upload/creating of product up into a few different sections?  In other words, the user would be able to upload all there images and then in the background I could run my create_var_product function to hopefully prevent timeout issues?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php

Comment: Do you get any other errors?

Comment: Nope, no errors, all uploads are successful unless they are trying to upload a lot of images which is most often the case..

Comment: Does @les answer help? How do you send the images? Could not figure yet...by `Ajax`?

Comment: Not sent through ajax, just using the post method in the form.. I thought about trying ajax and breaking that attached paste up into a file with the form and a file with the post requests..  Didn't have much success so I backed off that

Comment: Hmm, from your comment @les's I would say you should try. Have to tell you though, that you can come into conflict with max memory size of your browser, if you used `Base64` encoding...just `null` all variables then *after* the successful upload...have some chat room somewhere I guess, where we worked on that problem... : )

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your php.ini file. Look at editing at least the following:

```
max_input_time
upload_max_filesize
```

Check the documentation:

```
http://us3.php.net/ini.core
```

Comment: We asked our host about this and they told us we are not allowed to edit that file??  Im wondering if I can just create a php.ini file and stick it in the root?

Comment: WP Engine is who we are using for a host just because the client likes the ability to clone the site to a staging server

Comment: Although reading through this maybe it is possible? http://wpengine.com/support/what-functions-are-enabled-on-the-server-level/  Should I just create a php.ini file and try it?

Comment: Looks like your areas to edit are not disabled and you'd be free to upload your own with the appropriate changes

Comment: But then you had to reboot somehow.

Comment: @Derek Do you have a shared or dedicated hosting account?

Comment: @les, I believe it is shared, never thought to ask about dedicated

Comment: @Derek I tried asking on the Info Security Q&A and was essentially black balled... Check out my question though - maybe you'll get some ideas for how to "indirectly" reboot your server as I uniquely thought to ask ("indirectly" reboot via an account option or preference alteration/change (like choosing to use cloud flare - changes don't take effect until at most 24 hours - aka until they reboot the server??)). Let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following lines to the top of the script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I tried that and it didn't seem like it had any effect.