# Two input type field is not submitting in one form and unable to find error in php

Tags: php

In one form two input fields are not submitting. I think it's php version 5.6 issue
because it's working in php version 5.5, 5.4. and I am unable to find error.

HTML Code

```
<form action="quick-submit1.php" id="submission-form" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="docs"/> 
    <input type="file" name="docsss"/> 
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send File" name="submit">
</form>
```

After submit form (approx 5-7 min) it's showing this:

[image]

Comment: What about max upload file size and max iput time -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php?

Comment: In php.ini 

file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 2047M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
memory_limit = 2048M
max_input_vars = 80000
max_execution_time = 30000000
max_input_time = 500000
always_populate_raw_post_data =-1
mail.log = /php-email-contact-form/error_lo

Comment: it was working fine from last 15-20 days

Comment: please show your controller side code also.

Comment: I am not using any controller. it's just html code. when i submit the form, page is loading and loading

Comment: When i have changed the form method post to get it's show 404 page was not found.