# Increasing Execution Time for php

Tags: php, apache, timeout, debian, apache2

Update: This is not a dublicate question! I researched and tried many options/answers, but still, the web page is not allowing users to upload a file after exactly 20 seconds.

Update: I tried to switch from fast-cgi to php-fpm, but it did not work for me either. What else should I change in order to overcome timeout of 20 seconds?

When I am uploading large files via web browser, exactly after 20 seconds, it stops uploading. Specifically, approximately 40% of 100 MB file uploads fine during 20 seconds; I see the percentage of the upload under the Chrome browser. Then, the value of the percentage stops after 20 seconds and shows ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. I checked logs, but there is nothing regarding the issue.

My php.ini configuration as follows:

```
max_execution_time 300000
max_input_time 300000
upload_max_filesize 500M
post_max_size 500M
memory_limit 1024M
max_file_uploads 30
Timeout 8000 (in apache2.conf)
LimitRequestBody 0 (in htaccess)
```

What else should I change in order to increase an execution time? Obviously, there is some config that does not allow to upload a file after 20 seconds. My assumption is that there is something in Apache Configuration that must be tuned.

Comment: have you tried to set "set_time_limit(8000);" before your upload script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can file uploads time out in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php)

Comment: @Ciccio Yes, I tried, but it did not help.

Comment: @Morteza I tried 300000 but no luck so far

Answer (score 2):

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 100M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
   php_value memory_limit 100M
   php_value max_execution_time 300000
   php_value max_input_time 300000
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

insert this in .htaccess file. try whether its working or not

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried but it did not help.

Comment: Yes, I changed several times greater values than you provided. Obviously, there is another config that I have not faced yet.

Answer (score 0):

you should change max_input_time,upload_max_file_size and post_data_limit in php.ini file. It should work.

Comment: I can not find post_data_limit in my php.ini. Could you please tell me how can I find it? Or did you mean post_max_size when you wrote post_data_limit?

Comment: sorry my bad, it is post_max_size

Answer (score 0):

change values

- [max_execution_time](http://php.net/max-execution-time)  25000
- [max_input_time](http://php.net/max-input-time) 25000
- [memory_limit](http://php.net/memory-limit) 500M
- [display_errors](http://php.net/display-errors) On *;to see where is problem*
- [post_max_size](http://php.net/post-max-size) 500M
- [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/upload-max-filesize) 500M

and restart your apache or nginx tu load changes

in ubuntu you can use this command to restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: I tried everything you mentioned, but no progress so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Error is not shown as the web page becomes browser's default error page saying the site is not reachable

Comment: There is nothing wrong with upload code, as small files are uploaded normally, also, this is a new server, the upload worked perfectly in the old server

Comment: are you sure your server firewall not block your code?

Comment: whats your firewall?

Comment: I have never worked with firewall, could you tell me what should I do in order to check if there is a firewall, and get its name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150298/discussion-between-morteza-and-ulugbek).